# WiFi connection error: deauthenticating by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager, wicd

I'm encountering a connection issue to my university WiFi network that I cannot solve: when attempting to connect, I get the following message with `dmesg -T` :

```
[ven. oct. 11 12:32:04 2019] wlan0: deauthenticating from X by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

This problem has already been pointed out in the forum, but none of the solutions I tried worked:

- Disabling the powersave for WiFi (in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` set `wifi.powersave = 2` ).
- Changing from NetworkManager to WICD.
- Adding the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

  ```
  net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
  ```

None of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MX Linux and I face this problem literally every day, I don't know what is the root cause of the problem, but I do have a script which solves the problem for me every time. My wifi adapter is 'Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235', this is what resolves the problem for me.

```
sudo service networking stop
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi 
sudo modprobe iwldvm
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo service networking start
```

Answer (score -2):

I just met this problem this morning and fixed it.

Here is my suggestion.

Set your WiFi to no password mode to simplify the operation to connect.

Turn off net services:

```
systemctl list-units | grep -iE '(net|dhcp|wpa|conn|wicd)'
```

and you can see some services is running

```
systemctl stop [your running services]
```

Open your wlan0:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Connect wifi:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid [your wifi name]
```

DHCP IP:

```
dhclient wlan0
```